# Understanding of P2P (asynchronous vs. multithreading)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, p2p

[image]

I want to design a P2P-network.
In this network, every Peer should to two different tasks.

Task1: doing some stuff - collecting data, analyse data, decrypt data etc.

Task2: sharing data with other Peers in the network.

I will use Python and network-sockets.

The problem with classical synchronous programming-model: during Task1, the Task2 is waiting.

I can use non-blocking sockets - but the buffer-size on the sockets is really limited (kB). It is possible, that the socket-buffer of one peer can not store further data. If Task1 needs a lot of time to proceed, and the Peer can not read out the socket, it will block the whole network?
For example:
Node2 want to share some data with Node1, but Node1 is in Task1 and the socket buffer can not store some more data, Node2 has to wait for Node1?

What kind of approach will solve this problem?

Using Threads for each Task? Or asynchronous programming (Python asyncio?)?

What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: I don't think the p2p part is relevant to your question. You want socket programming basics.